# How should I read this link with Python? Pandas or BS4?

Tags: python, html, json, pandas

I am trying to read the following link with Pandas:

http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=3d82a096b5e846caa05ddc8e747a7fd&series_id=PET.WGIRIUS2.W

I've tried use `pd.read_json()`, which returned an error, `ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.`

I tried using `pd.read_csv` which returns a DataFrame without any rows, and all of the columns are in a list.

This is the first part of my code:

```
import pandas as pd

eia_key='<private>'

def link_category(id_number):
    return 'http://api.eia.gov/category/?api_key='+eia_key+'&category_id='+id_number

def link_series(id_number):
    return 'http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key='+eia_key+'&series_id='+id_number


'''U.S. Gross Inputs into Refineries, Weekly'''

page=link_series('PET.WGIRIUS2.W')
```

Then I try:

```
df=pd.read_csv(page)
```

and I get a mess with all of the table values as column names... but if I try

```
df=pd.read_json(page)
```

and I get the error mentioned above...

Any suggestions on the best way to read these EIA datasets with Python? I am open to using another library, like BS4 if that would be better.

Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: I recommend you post a sample copy of the link file and remove your API key from the question. It’s supposed to be something private

Comment: It seems like a regular json file, can’t you just use the `json` module? I don’t think it should belong in a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just want the `data` field out of the response.

```
import json, requests
d = json.loads(requests.get(page).text)
df = pd.DataFrame(d['series'][0]['data'])
```

`df` will get you the data you want I believe.